# Laravel Throttle overwrite in second

Tags: php, laravel, api, throttling

How to use laravel throttle in second instead of in minute?
I want to use this for chat app, and i think limiting it to second will be better.

and i tried to overwrite the laravel middleWareGroup throttle with this

```
Route::get("/v0/chat/get/{room}","chatController@chat_get")->middleware('throttle:120,1');
```

but the ->middleware() overwrite failed. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You must see ThrottlesLogin.php, at **lockoutTime** method to understand about lockoutTime.

```
protected function lockoutTime()
{
    return property_exists($this, 'lockoutTime') ? $this->lockoutTime : 60;
}
```

If you want to custom lockoutTime, init it in your controller $lockoutTime = ???

Comment: i can't find the locoutTime() method at ThrottlesLogin.php.

I tried this [[  Route::get("test","testController@route_test")->middleware('throttle:6,0.02');  ]] and works, thanks :)

Comment: what Laravel version are you using?

Comment: i use Laravel 5.3

Answer (score 1):

With this [issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/discussions/33931), you can use throttle in seconds.

> Now it is possible to use float for seconds, like 0.5 = 30 seconds.